# What can std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() be used for?

Tags: c++, std, numeric-limits

```
  unsigned int updateStandardStopping(unsigned int numInliers, unsigned int totPoints, unsigned int sampleSize)
    {
        double max_hypotheses_=85000;
        double n_inliers = 1.0;
        double n_pts = 1.0;
        double conf_threshold_=0.95

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sampleSize; ++i)
        {
            n_inliers *= numInliers - i;//n_linliers=I(I-1)...(I-m+1)
            n_pts *= totPoints - i;//totPoints=N(N-1)(N-2)...(N-m+1)
        }
        double prob_good_model = n_inliers/n_pts;

        if ( prob_good_model < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() )
        {
            return max_hypotheses_;
        }
        else if ( 1 - prob_good_model < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() )
        {
            return 1; 
        }
        else 
        {
            double nusample_s = log(1-conf_threshold_)/log(1-prob_good_model);
            return (unsigned int) ceil(nusample_s); 
        }
    }
```

Here is a selection statement:

```
if ( prob_good_model < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() )
{...}
```

To my understanding, the judgement statement is the same as(or an approximation to)

```
prob_good_model < 0
```

So whether or not I am right and where `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` can be used besides that?

Comment: Note that the episilon is the distance from 1 to the next number, not from 0 to the next number. There are many representable numbers between 0 and the epsilon in IEEE 754.

Comment: I printed episilon in the console, and the output is 2.22045e-16. So what I care here is whether it equals to `prob_good_model < 0`

Comment: It is very different to `< 0`

Comment: @Finley, No, it's not equivalent to `< 0`; all of the numbers between 0 and the epsilon differ in their result. Even if the epsilon were from 0 (this is `min` or `denorm_min`), it would still be a different result for 0 itself.

Comment: @chris So what is the true meaning of `prob_good_model < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`? Can you give me a reasonable speculation?

Comment: @chris or it just represents the variable prob_good_model is less than a very small number but not 0.

Comment: If you found this, it's likely an attempt at seeing whether `prob_good_model` is equal to 0 with some room for rounding error. However, it treats something like `prob_good_model = 1e-20` as equal to 0 despite the two being pretty far off for arithmetic done on very small values. Whether that difference is important depends on the code around this. Perhaps there's no chance of it ever producing a value lower than 10^-16 that it doesn't want to be treated as 0.

Comment: @chris I posted the codes around it, can you check it again? thank you:)

Comment: Personally, I think what this particular case is doing and the extra code needed to show it is distracting from the question of what the epsilon is used for. In any case, I don't have a great intuition for statistics (nor for floating-point while I'm at it), but I'd say it's probably acceptable for this use case that the epsilon is used. I'd also say the chance of encountering an error because of it increases with significant sample size.

Comment: They are using `epsilon` just as a small number. Although it is not related to its definition, and in some problems it might not be appropriately small, sometimes people use it as a measure of *small enough*. So, the condition `prob_good_model < epsilon` means that `prob_good_model` is close enough to zero. Here *enough* is according to the judgement of whoever wrote the code. Note how when the probability is close enough to zero, then the formula for `nusample_s` in the general case would return a very large number, then they return (what they consider a *large number*) `max_hypotheses_`.

Comment: Likewise, `1 - prob_good_model < epsilon` is being used here to mean that `prob_good_model` is close enough (for them) to `1`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The point of epsilon is to make it (fairly) easy for you to figure out the smallest difference you could see between two numbers.

You don't normally use it exactly as-is though. You need to scale it based on the magnitudes of the numbers you're comparing. If you have two numbers around 1e-100, then you'd use something on the order of: `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * 1.0e-100` as your standard of comparison. Likewise, if your numbers are around 1e+100, your standard would be `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * 1e+100`.

If you try to use it without scaling, you can get drastically incorrect (utterly meaningless) results. For example:

```
if (std::abs(1e-100 - 1e-200) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
```

Yup, that's going to show up as "true" (i.e., saying the two are equal) even though they differ by 100 orders of magnitude. In the other direction, if the numbers are much larger than 1, comparing to an (unscaled) epsilon is equivalent to saying `if (x != y)`--it leaves no room for rounding errors at all.

At least in my experience, the `epsilon` specified for the floating point type isn't often of a great deal of use though. With proper scaling, it tells you the smallest difference there could possibly be between two numbers of a given magnitude (for a particular floating point implementation).

In real use, however, that's of relatively little real use. A more realistic number will typically be based on the precision of the inputs, and an estimate of the amount of precision you're likely to have lost due to rounding (and such).

For example, let's assume you started with values measured to a precision of 1 part per million, and you did only a few calculations, so you believe you may have lost as much as 2 digits of precision due to rounding errors. In this case, the "epsilon" you care about is roughly 1e-4, scaled to the magnitude of the numbers you're dealing with. That is to say, under those circumstances, you can expect on the order of 4 digits of precision to be meaningful, so if you see a difference in the first four digits, it probably means the values aren't equal, but if they differ only in the fifth (or later) digits, you should probably treat them as equal.

The fact that the floating point type you're using can represent (for example) 16 digits of precision doesn't mean that every measurement you use is going to be nearly the precise--in fact, it's relatively rare the anything based on physical measurements has any hope of being even close to that precise. It does, however, give you a limit on what you can hope for from a calculation--even if you start with a value that's precise to, say, 30 digits, the most you can hope for after calculation is going to be defined by `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon`.

Comment: From a signal processing engineering perspective, epsilon looks like a "noise floor". Comparing your estimated precision to the noise floor (in practice log of ratio) give you a number in Decibel that you can call "noise margin" and can be used as a way to check if your float type is precise enough, or on the contrary raise an alarm. Not doing that means that your computations could come silently wrong because of a too short float type.

Comment: The epsilon is the **maximum** relative error between two numbers. This means that multiplied by the magnitude of the numbers, it is the **maximum** difference between two numbers. One example of a use that is has is to measure if the error of a computation is *acceptable*. If one computes a value by some method and gets `x` and by another one gets `y`, then if `abs(x-y)<=epsilon*abs(x)` the relative error is not larger than the maximum relative error that one can make at the scale of `x`. One can judge that `y` is an acceptable approximation of `y`.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: [sorry, I apparently missed this when posted] No. A suitably scaled value of epsilon gives the *smallest* difference that can be represented. So `abs(x-y)<=epsilon*abs(x)` doesn't make sense. The `<` part simply isn't possible, so this is equivalent to saying `if (x == y)`, allowing for no difference between the two methods of computation at all.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used on situation where a function is undefined, but you still need a value at that point. You lose a bit of accuracy, especially in extreme cases, but sometimes it's alright.

Like let's say you're using `1/x` somewhere but your range of x is [0, n[. you can use `1/(x + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())` instead so that 0 is still defined. That being said, you have to be careful with how the value is used, it might not work for every case.