# Generic function to accurately round floating-point to the nearest multiple of X

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am trying to write a generic function which rounds a `double` input value to the nearest multiple of `X`.

Due to floating-point precision reasons, the naive approach of just scaling and rounding can fail:

```
double round(double in, double multiple)
{
    return std::round(in / multiple) * multiple;
}
```

For example, since `0.15` is actually stored as `~0.14999999999999999445`, the above function when called to round to a multiple of `0.1` will return `0.1` rather than `0.2`, as can be seen in the following [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n3zrsn3oW).

So perhaps I should add an epsilon value, but what epsilon would be generic and sufficient?

I see there is a [`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon), and I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134073/955273) SO answer, I need to scale the value to the magnitude of the number I'm working with.

So should I use the `multiple` input parameter as my scaling factor?

If so, my `round` function becomes:

```
double round(double in, double multiple)
{
    const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * multiple;
    return std::round((in + epsilon) / multiple) * multiple;
}
```

Finally to make my function work for negative numbers, I use [`std::signbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) to work out if I should subtract epsilon instead of add:

```
double round(double in, double multiple)
{
    const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * multiple;
    const double incr = std::signbit(in) ? -epsilon : epsilon;
    return std::round((in + incr) / multiple) * multiple;
}
```

I've tested this with a range of inputs and multiples, and for the inputs I've tried it seems to work... but I'm uncertain.

Is my final version of `round` accurate?

If not, under what circumstances / for what inputs will it fail to produce the result I want it to, and is it possible to produce an accurate and generic function?

Comment: how about [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number please could you elaborate?

Comment: `rounded = x - std::fmod(x,multiple)` isnt that what you want to compute?

Comment: please clarify what input should procude what output and whats wrong about the results you get. In the text you use different values than in the godbolt link. I dont understand what you mean with "For example, since 0.5 is actually stored as ~0.14999999999999999445, the above function when called to round to a multiple of 0.1 will return 0.1 rather than 0.2"

Comment: oh sorry, i missed the "to nearest" part ;)

Comment: nevertheless I think its a typo. When you write "since 0.5 ..." it should be "since 0.15 ..."

Comment: why should 0.15 be rounded towards 0.2 rather than 0.1 ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that's exactly the right question. From a mathematical point of view the number `0.15` is exact and I was teached in school, that a trailing `5` should be rounded upwards. But you cannot do that in a consistent way with fuzzy floating point numbers as you cannot raliably predict, if the floating point implementation decides to store `0.15` as a slightly larger or slightly smaller value.

Comment: rounding upwards is convention. Its not a priori the only way to round. Rounding downwards for ties is as valid (though of course I understand that you'd like to have it at least consistent)

Comment: You're right but you couldn't implement that either in a consistent way.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number apologies - yes, 0.5 was a typo - should have been 0.15. Per your question why should 0.15 round to 0.2 and not 0.1, my understanding of math is that < 5 rounds down, and >= 5 rounds up, is that not correct?

Comment: maths is about conventions. if you want ties rounded up then thats it, if someone else want to round up thats as valid. I admit that I don't know the most commonly used convention or if there is one ;)

Comment: Note that not only is your input inexact, but the two possible outputs `0.1` and `0.2` are also stored inexactly, such that `rational(3, 2)` is not exactly halfway between them.  Even when all three are coerced to the nearest representable floating-point numbers, you may be surprised by e.g. `static_assert(.20 - .15 == .15 - .10)`

Comment: So the actual arguments to your function call are `round(0.1499999999999999944488849, 0.1000000000000000055511151)` and even the exact decimal 0.15000000000000 is closer to 0.1000000000000000055511151 than to 0.2000000000000000111022302

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your round function is working correctly. The value of `0.14999999999999999445` is rounded downwards, just as you woudl expect it to be. The problem you face is that `double` values can not represent arbitrary values due to the limited precision. Now consider the following program with your `round()` function:

```
double x = 0.15;
double y = 0.14999999999999999445;

std::cout << round(x, 0.1) << " ";
          << round(y, 0.1) << std::endl;
```

It outputs something like `0.1 0.1`. Because `x` and `y` have exactly the same value internally you will never get different results. Now if you add a small value before rounding (the epsilon you mentioned) you will get `0.2 0.2`. This might be correct for the `0.15` value but not for the other one anymore.

What I am trying to show you here is, that no matter how carefully you design your `round()` function, there will always be inconsitencies due to the precision limit. The *rounding cutoff* will always fluctuate. Some time it is a little bit above the *real* cutoff, some other time it may be a little bit below. There is nothing you can do about that.

So I am afraid, there is no satifying solution to your problem. You must accept a small fuzziness if you want to work with binary floating point numbers.

**Addition**
As you asked for an example where your second implementation (the one with the epsilon) fails, take a look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/K8q4a3G51). For `0.35` the rounded result is rounded towards `0.3`.

Comment: You are quite right. By the way, printing with `%.1f` also gives `0.1`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I suppose I need to specify a minimum precision? eg, if I were to say accurate to 10 decimal places, then `0.14999999999999999445` should be rounded to `0.15`

Comment: This answer is completely correct, aside from the conclusion.  The solution that allows 0.15 and 0.14999999999999999445 to round differently is to pass them around in a representation that can distinguish them, i.e. store them as strings or as a "BigDecimal" class.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe I should have said "base 2 floating point numbers" in the conclusion. Yes by using base 10 floating point numbers the problem would be less severe, as all numbers that can be typed (using base 10) are represented exactly.

Comment: @JakobStark thanks for the addition of the example! Really drives home the point!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Jakob Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71499607/2410359):

- OP expected 0.15, rounded to the nearest 0.1, to round to 0.20 and not 0.10. But *none* of 0.15, 0.1, 0.20 and 0.10 are *exactly* encodable in [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  Instead nearby values<sup>**</sup> (1st rounding) are used and the printed "0.10" is the *best* result given those encoded numbers.
- OP's issue is highlighted by using a value near the half-way point of 0.10 and 0.20 and not printing output to 17+ significant decimal places to see the issue.
- OP's `round(in / multiple) * multiple` compounds the issue even more as both the division and multiplication each incur rounding (2nd and 4th - the 3rd being `round()`).
- The displayed output is a 5th rounding.

To properly *round* to the nearest multiple either requires extended precision math (perhaps `long double` if it is wider) or simply tolerate getting an unexpected rounding with these near half-way cases.

I recommend against adding an *epsilon*.  Any non-crafted code is certain to create more corner errors.  The initial steps to round to a multiple require *exact* math.  Casual use of floating point `*/+-` does not provide that.

Instead consider a narrower problem: `double round_decimal(double x, int pow10)`.  `round_decimal(0.15, -1)` will still round to `0.1000000000000000055...` as the call is really `round_decimal(0.1499999999999999944..., -1)`, but at least reasonable code can be made to provide the best answers.  "Generic function to accurately round floating-point to the nearest multiple of X" is *far more* challenging.

---

<sup>**</sup>

```
0.100000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454101562500000
0.149999999999999994448884876874217297881841659545898437500000
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125000000
```